# Does opening a new terminal spawn a new shell?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am pretty new to Unix system commands and architecture. I find a few concepts pretty confusing and have been left with some unanswered questions, like: how many shells can be spawned in a single user's login session? does the number of shells have at all anything to do with a user's login?

While exploring system commands, I tried the following:

Opened a terminal window, say Terminal 1. Typed the following commands in order:

```
sleep 300
^z(ctrl+z)
bg
jobs
ps
```

Output for `jobs`:

```
[1]+  Running                 sleep 300 &
```

Output for `ps`:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
3301 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
4494 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep
4497 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

Without wasting any further time (300 seconds were far from being spent), I opened another terminal, lets name it Terminal 2. I entered the following commands in order:

```
jobs
ps
```

Output for `jobs`: -no output, command prompt returned-

Output for `ps`:

```
PID TTY          TIME CMD
4478 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
4496 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
```

I am wondering why the backgrounded `sleep` job (with Process ID 4494), executed in Terminal 1 wasnt listed in Terminal 2, neither with `jobs`, nor `ps`.

Can somebody please explain to me what exactly happened here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell in terminal 1 is bash with a PID of 3301. The shell in terminal 2 is bash with a PID of 4478. So yes, each terminal window is running an independent copy of the shell.

Comment: Hmm.. This untangles a few knots in the brain. But why is the backgrounded sleep process not listed when `ps` is entered in Terminal 2? Is it because it is a child process of bash1(PID 3301)? I was aware that `ps` lists the system wide running processes and `jobs` lists the processes managed only by the current shell. With this in mind, `ps` should have listed the sleep process in Terminal 2.

Comment: `ps` only lists processes on other TTYs with the appropriate options. Otherwise it restricts its output to the current TTY.

Comment: However, opening a new terminal need not run a shell (the `-e` option for xterm, etc., can run "any command").